# Downloading image from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download an image from firebase. Ever since they deprecated the get URI method however I haven't found an alternative that is working for me.

I have tried using the methods on firebase and multiple others on stackoverflow but none of the other solutions seem to be helping.

```
        profileImageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profile_images");
        String imageFile = "QxTTXQYPlaN2nEdel6LPZ5HxbE33.jpeg";
        StorageReference profRef = profileImageReference.child(imageFile);
        blogImageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_image);

        Glide.with(context).load(profRef).into(blogImageView);
```

From my understanding, this storagereference should point to the profile_images folder and then get the child of the image string. But it continues to fail to update on screen. I removed the request options exceptions because I wanted to see if it was overriding the downloads somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any info/exceptions being shown in the logcat when it tries to get the image? My original thought is, since you are using Firebase, you need to change `Glide` into `GlideApp` and create a class in your project that extends `AppGlideModule` in order to allow Glide to use Firebase image loading. So for example:

```
import android.content.Context;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.Registry;
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;
import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import java.io.InputStream;

@GlideModule
public final class TheGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
                new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }

}
```

Afterwards, Make the project and rebuild for Glide to create new associations and replace `Glide.with(context).load(profRef).into(blogImageView);` with `GlideApp.with(context).load(profRef).into(blogImageView);`

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked like a charm. I am now getting an error in the logcat. Luckily it is just saying object doesn't exist at that location which I'm sure is on me. You have saved me from my week of troubleshooting!